# Using contextual filters with multiple taxonomies plus dynamic paths

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have a content type, *FAQ*, which has the *Title*, *Body*, and *Related AP Course(s)* fields. The last is a node reference field, where the target is a *AP Exam* node.

I'd like to create a view page that follows the path URL pattern of the *AP Exam* content type which is *[content-type]/[ap-exam-category]/[ap-exam]*. The FAQ URL would be *[content-type]/[ap-exam-category]/[ap-exam]/faq*.

How can I create the contextual filter and path for this view?

So far, I've tried the following configuration.

#### Contextual Filters

- Content: AP Exam Category

[image: AP Exam Category]

- Content: Related AP Course(s)

[image: Related AP Courses]

#### Relationships

- field_ap_exam_category: Taxonomy term

[image: Taxonomy term]

Path: ap-exam/%/%/faq

No results are returned.

I've included the configuration for a most accurate representation.

[image: view config]

Comment: How you configured the contextual filters exactly? Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @leymannx Apologies, please see edits w/ screenshots.

Comment: Is ap-exam-category present on the FAQ CT? You haven't listed it. The [content-type] you want in your path is actually always fixed string and has nothing to do with FAQ CT? Is [ap-exam] the same as Related AP Course(s)? You don't seem to be using the Relationship anywhere. Why add it? Where do you plan to show this View? If you're expecting a contextual ID from URL it must be some node but you haven't mentioned it. Is it a block on AP Exam nodes? FYI your screenshots have a lot of unnecessary whitespace, it's useful to narrow your browser to remove the whitespace before taking screenshots.